# JS Loop inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Hello I have little problem with jquery.
First, I have  :

> VW BORA 1.9TDI 1990 1995
>   Audi A3 2.0TFSI 2006 2008

But I want to achieve :

> VW BORA 1.9TDI 1990
>   VW BORA 1.9TDI 1991
>   VW BORA 1.9TDI 1992
>   VW BORA 1.9TDI 1993
>   VW BORA 1.9TDI 1994
>   VW BORA 1.9TDI 1995
>   Audi A3 2.0TFSI 2006
>   Audi A3 2.0TFSI 2007
>   Audi A3 2.0TFSI 2008

**HTML code**:

```
<div class="make">
   <div class="name">VW BORA 1.9TDI</div><div class="start">1990</div><div class="end">1995</div>
</div>
<div class="make">
   <div class="name">Audi A3 2.0TFSI</div><div class="start">2006</div><div class="end">2008</div>
</div>
```

**JS code**:

```
$('div[class="make"]').each(function(index){
   var html = '';
   var start = $('.start').text();
   var end = $('.end').text();
   var name = $('.name').text();

   for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {
     html += '<div class="'+i+'">'+name+' '+i+'</div>';
   }
   $("#content").html(html)
});
```

If there is class .make with one content it's fine, but if class .make appears many times with different content, all the content is put together but it should be separate.

Like this:

> VW BORA 1.9TDIAudi A3 2.0TFSI 19902006
>   VW BORA 1.9TDIAudi A3 2.0TFSI 19902007
>   VW BORA 1.9TDIAudi A3 2.0TFSI 19902008
>   VW BORA 1.9TDIAudi A3 2.0TFSI 19902009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you :
note that `$(".class")` return always an array , so in your case you should access one by one and this by using the `index` value.

```js
$('div[class="make"]').each(function(index){
  
   var html = '';
   var links = '';
   var start = parseInt($(this).find(".start").text());
   var end = parseInt($(this).find(".end").text());
   var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
   
   for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {
       html += '<div class="'+i+'">'+name+' '+i+'</div>';
   }
   $("#content").append(html)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="make">
   <div class="name">VW BORA 1.9TDI</div><div class="start">1990</div><div class="end">1995</div>
</div>
<div class="make">
   <div class="name">Audi A3 2.0TFSI</div><div class="start">2006</div><div class="end">2008</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: You should rather use `$(this).find(".start")` to navigate to current element

Comment: This is actually pretty bad practice what this example does. It's slow and not necessary. Something like `$($('.start')[index]).text()`is horrorful to see. Think about what is does: Get all `.start` elements each loop, get only one pure dom element out of jQuery by `[index]` and then make it an jQuery object again with `$()` and then get the content with `.text()`. Why would you do this? `$(".start", $(this)).text()` and done. Or even better, make `$(this)` a variable before, to only cast `this` into an jQuery object once. Like in my example ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't determine where jQuery has to look for the other elements, so it graps all. Just let him search for `start`, `end` and `name` in the parent context.

And use `html()` instead of `text()` to only get the elements content.

```
$('div[class="make"]').each(function(index){
    var parent = $(this),
        html = links = '',
        start = $('.start', parent).html(),
        end = $('.end', parent).html(),
        name = $('.name', parent).html();

    for( var i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
        html += '<div class="' + i + '">' + name + ' ' + i + '</div>';
    }

    $("#content").html(html)
});
```

That should work.

Comment: $("#content").append(html); would do better to avoid erasing content for each new div.make found ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Notice that you are trying to change `#content`'s innerHTML inside each iteration, so you get the html overriden. You might want to update the `#content` just once when you're finished with the loop.)

In ES6 version:

```
const makes = document.querySelectorAll('.make');
let string = '';

Array.from(makes).forEach(div => {
    const text = div.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    const end = +div.querySelector('.end').textContent;
    let start = +div.querySelector('.start').textContent;

    while(start <= end) {
        string += `<div class='${start}'>${text} ${start++}</div>\n`;
    }
});
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = string;
```

Old Javascript version:

```
var makes = document.querySelectorAll('.make');
var string = '';

Array.from(makes).forEach(function(div) {
    var text = div.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    var end = +div.querySelector('.end').textContent;
    var start = +div.querySelector('.start').textContent;

    while(start <= end) {
        string += '<div class"' + start + '">' + text + ' ' + (start++) + '</div>\n';
    }
});
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = string;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to find elements inside the currently active, but you do a global lookup. To only search in the current scope do something like this:

```
var start = $(this).children('.start').text(); // same for .end/.name
```

You will also want to explicitly convert the value retrieved via `text()` into a number like this:

```
for (var i = Number(start); i <= Number(end); i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Also, defining variables you iterate over and not just use them is generally a good practice.

jQuery provides some pretty nice utilities to work with DOM elements so you don't have to use strings - like this:

```
var $div = $("<div>").text(name).addClass(i);
$("#content").append($div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues in your code:

```js
$('div[class="make"]').each(function(index){
   var html = '';
   var start = $('.start').text();
   var end = $('.end').text();
   var name = $('.name').text();
```

- You are looping on each div, but not searching based on current div. You should rather use `$(this).find(".start")` to get relevant fields.
- `var start = $('.start').text();` this will have value `"1990"` and not `1990`. You should manually convert it into integer using `parseInt`.
- `$("#content").html(html)` this will replace html in every iteration. Either use `.append()` or declare `html` variale outsite and then use `.html`. Note, its a bad practice to modify DOM in loop. I would suggest to move variable outside and update dom once.

[Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/5rkg8fod/)